Can I use thermal camera to see what parts of a CPU/GPU chip are more hot?
I watched videos from youtube where some people use thermal cameras in order to depict how hot is a CPU/GPU under the thermal camera. However, a thermal camera shows the CPU/GPU that is hot. I need to identify how the hot is distributed along the parts of the CPU in more detail. So, my question is this:

Can a thermal camera give me detailed temperature on specific parts of the CPU/GPU chip?
Can I get a matrix with detailed temperatures of the CPU hot, with let's say 1 mm sampling? So, I mean to give me the temperature of the CPU and update every 1mm across the CPU/GPU chip.


Can your CPU survive running with the die exposed (no heatsink)?

A Raspberry Pi yes!

Of course cannot see inside the die, but I am just curious if a thermal camera can show me the heat distribution.

isn't  that what a thermal camera does?

As the people below state, who are far more experienced than me, it is a bit difficult what I want to achieve...

A thermal camera will show you the temperature of the package, not the die inside it.
Assuming you can remove any heatsinks without damage and run the CPU without heatsink.
If the package is metal like on your Raspberry Pi, the metal conducts heat rather well, so the temperature of the metal will be quite uniform.
Shiny metal also reflects IR like a mirror reflects light, so you likely can't even measure temperature of the CPU metal package with a thermal camera, unless you put something on it like Kapton to transfer the heat from shiny metal to the polyimide tape that is not a reflective material for IR wavelengths.
So:

It depends, it could, but it might not, depending on the materials.

If it can, it means a 1cm x 1 cm CPU needs 10 x 10 pixels. IR thermal cameras are not very high resolution, unless expensive. They might need a macro lens, but one with high enough resolution could work without macro lens.



It's not just reflection; metals also tend to have very low emissivity. I usually use black spray-paint (the high-temp stuff sold for fixing the paint on grills) for stuff like this; it has an emissivity very close to 1.

With the device packaged, the package heat spreader will blur out any thermal detail. You will get a general idea what section is hotter with the heat spreader in place, perhaps to a quadrant level of detail. Hint, when thermal imaging metal packages, place matte Scotch tape over the metal parts. Metal has a very low emissivity, plastic has a high emissivity.
If you decap the device (remove the heat spreader) to show the bare die, you will be able to see temperature variations on the die. You'll need a macro extension tube for the lens so you can close focus if you want any detail. The last time I did this was with a very expensive thermal imaging system with interchangeable lenses. This gave pretty good detail so we could thermally map blocks of circuitry.
